Re-run all jobs button sometimes missing in GitHub actions
I sometimes need to re-run GitHub actions jobs more than once.
But, in some cases the re-run all jobs button is missing in GitHub actions. In the same repository sometime it's there, and sometimes missing:


could not find the logic in it - why sometimes it's missing.

Ok so apparently the 're-run' option becomes unavailable after 30 days as can be seen here
in the documentations
